# If htaccess runs into 400, 401 or 403 save the request_uri and redirect to a custom page

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I already have the redirect to a custom error page. But I want't to get the requested URI from where the 400, 401 or 403 hit. I'm a total scrub in htaccess coding. This is what I have so far:

```
ErrorDocument 400 'example.com/customerror.php'
ErrorDocument 401 'example.com/customerror.php'
ErrorDocument 403 'example.com/customerror.php'
```

Now I somehow need to save the request uri if it hits 400, 401 or 403 and call it later from the custom errorpage PHP.

EXAMPLE how it should work:

1. User requests a page: example.com/wp-content/plugins .htaccess
2. .htaccess blocks it
3. .htaccess saves the request_uri (/wp-content/plugins)
4. .htaccess redirects to example.com/customerror.php customerror.php
5. page shows the saved request_uri (/wp-content/plugins)

Can someone please help me with step 3 and 5 please. I got the others covered already. All help is higly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the header `HTTP_REFERER` which is the previous request URI, on your `customerror.php` to save it a database or in file.

Comment: I've tried `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` already but it will not show me anything. I'm not 100% sure but it's probably because htaccess is redirecting the `example.com/wp-content/plugins` request to my custom errorpage before letting the user through. Therefore it is not referred from `/wp-content/plugins` ?